# How to ignore terms containing in the summation of multiplications

Tags: equation-solving

```
n=4;L=3;
p0[n_Integer]:=
Product[
Sum[Subscript[r, k][l, l], {l, L - 1}], {k, n}] // 
Expand;
```

How to ignore terms containing three or more multiplications of [2, 2] in this sum. Example, I want to ignore this term...

```
Subscript[r, 1][1, 1] Subscript[r, 2][2, 
2] Subscript[r, 3][2, 2] Subscript[r, 4][2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eq = p0[4] // Expand;
```

`FullForm[eq]` reveals how the terms that should be remove are defined:

```
(* Times[Subscript[r, 1][2, 2], Subscript[r, 2][2, 2], 
         Subscript[r, 3][2, 2], Subscript[r, 4][2, 2]] *)
```

Then, we can find those and replace them with zeros (here I generalized the pattern to allow having three or more multiplications of the [2,2] terms):

```
eq /. Times[Subscript[r, a_][2, 2], 
            Subscript[r, b_][2, 2], 
            Subscript[r, c_][2, 2], ___] :> 0
```